# DocumentListener Validation Error in MVC Application

Tags: java, swing

I am making a swing MVC application , to know the intricacies of GUI design using the Swing Framework . My JDK Version is 7 and I have a simple application that contains a dialog having a textfield for storing the path to a file , a browse button  , 2 textfields for user id and password and 2 buttons for Update and Cancel functionalities.

Clicking on these buttons simply shows a dialog with either Update or Cancel message on it.

I planned to use DocumentListener to validate the textfield components.

In the UI i have the following code to create the 2 textfields :

```
public JPasswordField getMyPasswordField() {
        if(myPasswordField == null)
        {
            myPasswordField = new JPasswordField();
            myPasswordField.setBounds(133, 93, 163, 21);
            myPasswordField.getDocument().putProperty("Owner", "myPasswordField");
        }
        return myPasswordField;
    }


public JTextField getMyUserNameField() {
        if(myUserNameField== null)
        {
            myUserNameField = new JTextField();
            myUserNameField.setBounds(133, 66, 163, 21);

            myUserNameField.getDocument().putProperty("Owner", "myUserNameField");

        }
        return myUserNameField;
    }
```

In the controller I used the following code :

```
myReferenceUI.getMyUserNameField().getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
myReferenceUI.getMyPasswordField().getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
```

And in the method implementation I wrote the following :

```
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        Object owner = e.getDocument().getProperty("Owner");
         changed(owner);

         }
    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        Object owner =e.getDocument().getProperty("Owner"); 
        changed(owner);

    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        Object owner =e.getDocument().getProperty("Owner"); 
        changed(owner);

    }

   public void changed(Object e)

   {

       System.out.println(e.toString());

     if(  e.toString().equals("myUserNameField"))
     {
         if(myReferenceUI.getMyUserNameField().getText().equals("") )
         {
             myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton().setEnabled(false);
             return ;
         }

     }

         if(  e.toString().equals("myPasswordField"))
         {
             if(myReferenceUI.getMyPasswordField().getText().equals("") )
             {
                 myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton().setEnabled(false);
                 return ;
             }

         }

          myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton().setEnabled(true);
```

}

My intent was to enable the update button only if the 2 textboxes for username and password have non null values.

The listener events fire properly and the update button is disabled in case of null entry in the username / password fields.

But after entering any value in these fields , if i press backspace and erase the text , the update button remains disabled.

What can i do to get rid of this condition ?

Comment: what do you mean by null entry ?

Comment: @Sage This refers to either of the username / password fields being empty

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DocumentListener` that is aware of both the documents that you want to follow. For example:

```
private static class PasswordValidator implements DocumentListener {
    private final Document[] documents;
    private final JComponent component;

    PasswordValidator(JComponent component, Document... docs) {
        this.component = component;
        documents = docs;
        for (Document doc : docs) {
            doc.addDocumentListener(this);
        }
        validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        validate();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        if (e.getDocument().getLength() == 0) {
            component.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // Attribute change - ignore
    }

    private void validate() {
        for (Document doc : documents) {
            if (doc.getLength() == 0) {
                component.setEnabled(false);
                return;
            }
        }
        component.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

That particular implementation would then be used something like:

```
new PasswordValidator(myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton(), myReferenceUI.getMyUserNameField().getDocument(), myReferenceUI.getMyPasswordField().getDocument());
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around my troubles by attaching PropertyChangedListeners to both my username and password fields and the following bit of code :

```
public void setUpdateButtonState()
    {
        if((myReferenceUI.getMyUserNameField().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")
                || String.valueOf(myReferenceUI.getMyPasswordField().getPassword())
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("")  ))

{
    myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton().setEnabled(false);
}
else
{

    myReferenceUI.getMyUpdateButton().setEnabled(true);

}
```